# Wrinng a RuntimeException

Tags: java, exception

Suppose I want to have an unchecked exception for a specific "case" in my code-- 
say when a queue is 75% full. All I need is an Exception saying "queue has reached the 75% threshold".

One-- the most obvious(?) way of doing this is

```
public class QueueT extends RuntimeException {
  QueueT () {
      super("queue has reached the 75% threshold");
  }
}
```

All&only use I have for this exception is

```
  try {
     // some stuff here
     throw new QueueT();
     } catch (QueueT e) {
        System.out.print("<<"+e+">>");
       }
```

what I'm wondering is-- what exactly i'm gaining by going with the above-- writing an exception--
rather than the below. Recall: i have no other use-- won't be needing those other methods of **Throwable** or anything else.

```
  try {
     // some stuff here
     throw new RuntimeException("queue has reached the 75% threshold");
     } catch (RuntimeException e) {
          System.out.print("<<"+e+">>");
        }
```

From what i see, the only gain i have is the comfort of calling the constructor without bothering a **String** attribute.

It's even gainful-- i can easily parameterize the threshold that i'll throw the exception on:

```
 // setting the percentage value here
 throw new RuntimeException("queue has reached the" + percentage + "% threshold");
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Creating your own type of exception you can use different try-catch blocks for your exception and other RuntimeException and you can add more funcionality if you need to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you gain is that in your first example,

```
try {
   // some stuff here
   throw new QueueT();
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
   System.out.print("<<"+e+">>");
}
```

if you replace `catch (RuntimeException e)` with `catch (QueueTe)`:

```
try {
   // some stuff here
   throw new QueueT();
} catch (QueueTe e) {
   System.out.print("<<"+e+">>");
}
```

Here, you can very exactly say what type of error to catch. Otherwise, you may have another part of your code throw a run time exception and your code to deal with a nearly full queue may try to be applied to an exception totally unrelated to the queue.  If you only catch the `QueueT` exception, you can apply code better and more exactly.

Comment: copy-paste error-- correcting it. it ought to be a QueueT exception.

Comment: Oh ok. Well, the 2nd half of my answer still applies

Comment: i was wondering whether there's anything else to it "behind the scenes" but i guess this is it. haven't had a close look at the 'cause' yet. certainly makes a diff. on supressed exceptions. thx for the input.

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose I want to have an unchecked exception for a specific "case" in my code-- say when a queue is 75% full. All I need is an Exception saying "queue has reached the 75% threshold".

This is a poor case for exceptions. Exceptions are not used for business logic; they are used for *exceptional* conditions. This seems to be an *expected* scenario and more like a notification than an exception. How would you expect a person who catches this exception to react? Just ignore it? If so, what is the purpose of the exception? Also, using exceptions in this manner is not performant at all since it has to fill in the stack trace, and doing this repeatedly will make your performance very bad.

As to your other question, the benefit of using your own runtime exception versus `RuntimeException` is that you now have your own exception that is (hopefully) semantically appropriate, which you can throw or handle appropriately. Simply using `RuntimeException` by itself doesn't really give that much information.

Comment: I totally agree with the 1st part

Answer (score 0):

The interest of the first call is easy to understand if you change a bit the catch clause :

```
 try {
// some stuff here
throw new QueueT();
} catch (QueueT e) {
   System.out.print("<<"+e+">>");
}
```

So you will only catch instance of QueueT instead of potential others runtimes like null pointer, such kind of exception you would better let propagate to the entry point in order to detect some coding or design issue.
In Fact in the code you wrote first, you won't be able to differentiate the expected full queue case from a real runtime error. You will lost the error information and the program will act as if the queue were full whereas it isn't

A good practice is to never catch the exception super type, neither runtime nor throwable (the worst one).

Another one is to name an exception with the exception suffix : QueueAboutFullException for example.

Another one is not to use programming by exception if the place you catch the exception is about the same than the one where you throw it. Prefer a simple if because it cost much less than the interruption

Comment: For the 2nd part just add a percentage property when declaring the exception class, and add a constructor which will handle this parameter (like `super("queue has reached the" + percentage + "% threshold")`